# How to fix mySQL query to find all dates of month mapped with total Count for each date including zeros?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timestamp, left-join

I have an **orders** table with a Date column of timestamp.
I want to **count** number of orders placed for **each** date including zeros for dates when No order was placed,  like this:

> TotalOrders--------- Date
>
> 12------------------ 01/02/2019
>
> 0------------------- 02/02/2019
>
> 7------------------- 03/02/2019
>
> 0------------------- 04/02/2019
>
> 4------------------- 05/02/2019
>
> 0------------------- 06/02/2019

I searched this here and got one solution:

> select COUNT(o.OrderID) AS TotalOrders,  a.date
>
> from ( select date_add('2019-07-01', INTERVAL 
>   n5.num*10000+n4.num*1000+n3.num*100+n2.num*10+n1.num DAY ) as date
>
> from (select 0 as num    union all select 1    union all select 2    union
>
> all select 3    union all select 4    union all select 5    union all select 6    union all select 7    union all select 8    union all
>    select 9) n1,
>
> (select 0 as num    union all select 1    union all  select 2    union all select 3    union all select 4    union all
>    select 5    union all select 6    union all select 7    union all
>    select 8    union all select 9) n2,
>
> (select 0 as num    union all
>    select 1    union all select 2    union all select 3    union all
>    select 4    union all select 5    union all select 6    union all
>    select 7    union all select 8    union all select 9) n3,
>
> (select 0 as num    union all select 1    union all select 2    union all select 3 
>    union all select 4    union all select 5    union all select 6
>    union all select 7    union all select 8    union all select 9) n4,
>
> (select 0 as num    union all select 1    union all select 2    union
>    all select 3    union all select 4    union all select 5    union all
>    select 6    union all select 7    union all select 8    union all
>    select 9) n5
>
> ) a
>
> LEFT JOIN orders o ON MONTH(o.Date)=  MONTH(a.date)
>
> AND YEAR(o.Date) = YEAR(a.date) where MONTH(a.date) ='7' and
>
> YEAR(a.date) = '2019'  GROUP BY a.date order by a.date

**EDIT**: 
As in July 2019 total 4 orders were placed so when I used above solution,  it gives me **4** result for each dates. instead It should have showed order Count for respective date and zero for dates with no order. But it shows 4 for each date. Please let me know where I'm doing it wrong. my Orders table is:

**orders(OrderID(p.k), Date, totalPrice, CustomerID)**

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data has no examples from July 2019.

I would also suggest that you use ranges for the `where` comparison, so for January 2019:

```
where a.date >= '2019-01-01' and a.date < '2019-02-01'
```

Comment: No. I do have total 4 orders in month of july. Now instead of zeros, it is actually showing 4 value in front of each date.

Comment: Please see my EDIT in question